# Unable to access Google Chrome APIs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome Extension and have tried to access the storage API. However I get a console error:

> notes.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined
>           at HTMLTextAreaElement.save_notes (notes.js:25)

Commenting out the storage.sync call and uncommenting the privacy.services call (strictly to test a 2nd Chrome API) I get this error instead:

> notes.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'services' of
>   undefined at HTMLTextAreaElement.save_notes (notes.js:30)

**Anyone know what not being able to access any Chrome API explictly listed in the manifest.json permissions could be a sign of?**

---

Here's my **javascript** file. Under testing, the error occurs on the "save_notes" function call.

```
console.log("note.js connected")

///// select the text area

var note_area = document.getElementById('notetext')

//// todo Create a function to save the textarea to local storage
// todo First check & load any previously saved notes

;(function load_notes() {
  if (note_area === "") {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("stored_obj", function(resultObj) {
      note_area.value = resultObj.stored_obj
      console.log("Attempted to load notes into a blank note area. Did it run correctly?")
    })
  }
})()

function save_notes () {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
     stored_obj: note_area.value
   }, function () {
        console.log("Saved into Chrome Storage")
   })

  // chrome.privacy.services.autofillEnabled.get({}, function(details) {
  //  if (details.value)
  //    console.log('Autofill is on!');
  //  else
  //    console.log('Autofill is off!');
  //});

}

note_area.addEventListener('blur', save_notes)

//// setup a blur handler in notes.html to fire function save_notes
// could not be done (inline JS). I need to add a listener and a function in this file

function console_fire() {
  console.log ('fired the console log')
}
```

Here's my **manifest.json** file:

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Mindless Blocker",
  "version": "0.1",

  "description": "Block mindless distractions and have a place to take notes for followup during free time",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "cloud-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "privacy"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting js error on each try or there is any specific scenario? Are you able to call other chrome apis?

Comment: Yes it occurs each time. I tried another API and the same error type happened.

Comment: Check your background page console log for any error. Sometime errors occurs due ti other errors.

Comment: Looks like there are no additional errors on the background page: http://i.imgur.com/Az4VDlR.png

Comment: Yes there are no additional errors. But the screenshot you shared showing console logs of you content script. I asked you to check console logs of the background page. Errors in background page may also cause errors in content script.

Comment: I see notes.html in the address bar, which would make that the background page, right? If not what background page are you referring to? I am not running the extension with Google or some other site running behind it. I'm running the extension itself in the browser (and when I inspect the extension/popup in the special Chrome console, it shows the same issue)